# How add registry keys with CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY?

Tags: cmake, nsis, cpack

I need to install some registry key for a NSIS installer. I'm working with CPACK and I found this command `CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY`. There is not much doc on the Internet but I guess :

```
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY
"MyReg\\\\MyKey" "${INSTALL_DIR}\\\\" 
)
```

Or something not much different.

I also read this on an other topic:

```
list(APPEND CPACK_NSIS_EXTRA_INSTALL_COMMANDS " 
                InstallDirRegKey HKCU \"Software\\Test\" \"RegEntry\"
               ")
```

But I didn't understand why use this last command instead of the CPACK command.

Thank you for your help

Comment: InstallDirRegKey just sets the default $InstDir path from a value in the registry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about CPack but I guess CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY also maps to [InstallDirRegKey](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/InstallDirRegKey) and cannot be used to write generic values to the registry.

Try something like this to insert raw NSIS instructions:

```
SET(CPACK_NSIS_EXTRA_INSTALL_COMMANDS "
  WriteRegStr HKLM 'Software\\\\MyApp' 'MyValue' 'MyData'
  WriteRegDWORD HKLM 'Software\\\\MyApp' 'OtherValue' '4'
   ")
SET(CPACK_NSIS_EXTRA_UNINSTALL_COMMANDS "
  DeleteRegKey HKLM 'Software\\\\MyApp' 
 ")
```